How to login to gmail using python requests?
Given that using google API is not an option, I'm trying to login to gmail using selenium and obtain the cookies to reuse them in python requests (because otherwise I'll have to reimplement the client side logic which enrypts the password and many other steps that are complicated). This is what I tried in selenium:
from time import sleep

from selenium.common import (
    ElementNotInteractableException,
    StaleElementReferenceException,
)
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

from scripts.utils import click_button

driver = Chrome()
timeout = 30
driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)
form_values = {
    'input[type=email]': 'email',
    'input[type=password]': 'password',
}
driver.get('https://mail.google.com')
click_button(
    driver, driver.find_element('xpath', '//a[contains(@href, "accounts.google")]')
)
for css, value in form_values.items():
    while True:
        try:
            field = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
                expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(('css selector', css))
            )
            field.send_keys(value)
            driver.find_element('xpath', '//span[contains(text(), "Next")]').click()
            break
        except (ElementNotInteractableException, StaleElementReferenceException):
            sleep(3)

which gives the error (could not sign you in ...) below:
could not sign you in
So I try the same approach using undetected-chromedriver instead and it sometimes works and most times the browser hangs and stops responding after any of the submissions or if I call any of the selenium methods while the page is loading. Here's the versions used on macOS Monterey:
Chrome                  127.0.6533.89
selenium                4.23.1
undetected-chromedriver 3.5.5

If I manage to login with selenium, I load the cookies into a requests.session for further reuse.
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
session = requests.session()
for cookie in cookies:
    session.cookies.set(
        cookie['name'], cookie['value'], domain=cookie['domain'], path=cookie['path']
    )
response = session.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0')

However, despite being authenticated (assuming the selenium login eventually worked), I get the error (We’re sorry, but your account is temporarily unavailable ...) shown below
account unavailable
....................


I suspect this would go against gmail TOS.  2. Why not use the gmail api 3. why not use the smtp server?  4. I hope you are doing this with a dummy gmail account. I have heard of people having their accounts band for less sthan this.

